# Firefox Developer Edition opens as separate item on dash

Tags: fedora, gnome, firefox

I installed Firefox Developer Edition as per [this guide](https://medium.com/@js_debugger/how-to-install-firefox-developer-edition-on-ubuntu-1c7f5f2b6883) (except I did `sudo chmod +X firefox-developer-edition.desktop` as well).

I can find Firefox with the correct icon in my Applications menu, but when I open it, it opens in a window with no icon. I previously had it pinned to my dash and it wouldn't open under that either. It just looks like this [image].

Here is my full `.desktop` file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Firefox Developer Edition
GenericName=Firefox Developer Edition
Exec=/opt/firefox/firefox --class "Firefox Developer Edition"
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/firefox/browser/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
Type=Application
Categories=Application;Network;X-Developer;
Comment=Firefox Developer Edition Web Browser.
StartupWMClass=Firefox Developer Edition
StartupNotify=true
```

I tried doing `xprop WM_CLASS`, but nothing happens when I click on any windows.

I'm on Fedora 36, and using Dash to Panel v50 if it matters.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `StartupWMClass=<executable_name>`. The executable name is displayed when it's open. In my case: `StartupWMClass=firefox-aurora`